# Why the generalized derivatives defined? Why was it needed?

Tags: derivatives, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

While I was searching "why the generalized derivatives defined?", I saw the expression:

"An extension of the idea of a derivative to some classes of non-differentiable functions."
on https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Generalized_derivative . But I need more knowledge about the emergence of the generalized derivative (or in the sense of Sobolev). Why this type derivatives defined? Why was it needed?

Can somebody recommend a source to me?

Comment: As far as I know one started to look at weaker differentiability concepts as in the field of partial differential equations one often can not find classical solutions.

Comment: Do we really need a reason before generalising a concept? Surely sometimes it's nice just to know whether something works in more contexts.  If I told you "I have a key that can open many locks", wouldn't you be at least a little curious whether it opens ALL locks?

Comment: good metaphor @Jam. You are right!  Of course, I can not query the reason for all the generalities. But for improving, sometimes I should learn what the exit point. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very interesting survey on the birth of Sobolev spaces: [file](https://edoc.hu-berlin.de/bitstream/handle/18452/3267/2.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y)